# Updating with Nested Select Statements

Tags: t-sql, sql-update

I have a table that holds 3 fields of data: `Acct#`, `YMCode`, and `EmployeeID`.  The YMCode is an Int that is formatted `201308`, `201307`, etc.  For each `Acct#`, I need to select the `EmployeedID` used for the `YMCode` `201308` and then update all of the other `YMCodes` for the Acct# to the `EmployeedID` used in `201308`.

so for each customer account in the table...

```
Update MyTable
Set EmployeeID = EmployeeID used in YMCode 201308
```

Having a hard time with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in a transaction and look at the results before committing, but I think this is what you want:

```
UPDATE b
SET EmployeeID = a.EmployeeID
FROM MyTable a
INNER JOIN MyTable b
ON a.[Acct#] = b.[Acct#]
where a.YMCode = 
(SELECT MAX(YMCode) from MyTable)
```

To get max YMCode, just add select statement at the end.

Comment: Strangely, when I ran this on my larger production database, it did not update everything.  Some accounts it updated properly and other accounts it ignored completely.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/36058/updating-with-nested-select-statements?tab=general